# Background's/JavaScript show/work locally, not on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background, local

When I check my page stored locally on my computer everything loads fine, but when I upload it to my server, the background/slideshow transition thing doesn't work, they don't even show up. here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>blah</title>
<meta name="description" content="Add Site Description Here">
<meta name="keywords" content="Add Keywords Here">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/Easy_Background.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>

<!-- Fullsscreen Background -->
<script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var background = new Easy_Background({
          background_color: "none",
          pattern: "img/patterns/pattern-4.png",
          autoplay: "true",
          autoplayTime: 5,

          images:["img/fullscreen/1.jpg", 
                  "img/fullscreen/2.jpg",
                  "img/fullscreen/3.jpg", 
                  "img/fullscreen/4.jpg",
                  "img/fullscreen/5.jpg",
                  "img/fullscreen/6.jpg", 
                  "img/fullscreen/7.jpg"],
          images_sizing: "fill", // fill || adjust || stretch || repeat

          animationIn: { attribute:["y", "alpha"], // x || y || alpha 
                value:  ["1px", 0],
                easing: ["easeOutCubic", "swing"],
                time: [0.7, 1.5],
                delay:  0 },
          animationOut: { attribute:[],
                 value:   [],
                 easing:  [],
                 time:  [],
                 delay: 0 }
        });
        $('body').click(background.next);
      });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
  });
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a webbrowser (I prefer Chrome), hit F12 (this opens a webinspector in Chrome and some other browser). Look for a "console" tab and reduce the errors to zero.

In fact I think you missed to upload some files.

By the way there is no JAVA Code. You mean Javascript. Thas something comlpletely different.

**update**
Your linked javascript resources:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/Easy_Background.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
```

But you brother knows this better than me.

Comment: missed uploading some files? what files you thinking?

Comment: the images probably, as they don't show up. Also check if you have the same path structure on your webserver. Using the net tab of the mentionned inspector will show wether the images get loaded propperly or return a 404 because they are not found...

Comment: you're onto something, when i updated my javascript files, i checked the page after deleting them and before reupping them and the page looked exactly the same. they're not being (read?) i think. what would change between checking my page locally to checking after uploaded to server that would make my javascript resources not be seen/read?

Comment: Just ask you browser, The browser knows it best. There are tools for IE, FF and Chrome.

Comment: care to expound a little, what tools?

Comment: Install the google chrome browser and hit "F12" OR use IE9+ and press F12 OR install firefox and the firebug addon (there should be a new icon in the lower right corner). I would use the chromebrowser.

Comment: nevermind. the easy background js got messed up during uploading i guess. i fixed it. everything fine now. thanks

Comment: Than you should mark my answer as helpful and close the question.